How to batch modify plenty of mysqli procedural queries to prepared statements?
I would like to modify once for all my old styles queries to prepared statements and get rid of the care for mysqli escaping etc.
After analysis, I decided to stick with mysqli prepared statements.
I am considering two strategies:

Use my PHP custom try_query() function I use every time I make a query and make it analyze every query, converting to prepared statements on the fly. Seems complicated and slowing down everything.

Batch convert the source code


As I prefer solution 2, my question now is:
Which kind of language/website/software would be the best suited to find the queries' texts, analyze them, and write the new requests by transferring the parameters in the same source file?
I tried manual work, many mistakes, and a slow process.


There is no solution as far as I know. 2. There is a tool called Rector but I cannot find a rule for your case. 3. stick to mysqli_execute_query() (instead of mysqli_prepare). 4. You can even use it instead of your try_query()


I've occasionally handled simple transformations with regexp find/replace in PhpStorm, but it requires significant handholding and manual fixups. It's hard to do it in bulk, I was doing it when the queries followed simple formats.

I doubt a tool like that exists. Some time ago Rector tried something similar and it turned out to be near impossible task.
You need to do it all manually. You need to treat every instance of an unparameterized query as a bug because in a way that's what it is. You need to review your whole code and find where a variable should not be interpolated in an SQL query directly and fix it. This may uncover other bugs too. Your code may contain dynamically built queries where interpolating a constant/whitelisted part of the query is the only way to go, e.g. whitelisted table/column names. Writing software to do it automatically and reliably for you would require a fully-fledged SQL parser with a bunch of rules.
This kind of manual work should have been done when migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5. At the time, mysqli was introduced as a temporary solution for these old projects. Simple queries would have been replaced with a parameterized statement and places where it was not so easy could replace mysql_escape_string with mysqli_escape_string and keep on working until a bigger code refactoring could be done.
What you can do is follow the same strategy with your existing project. Keep on replacing each query one by one until you fix all of it. Nowadays mysqli prepared statements are much easier to use than in the past. You can use mysqli_execute_query() to parameterize your query with minimal hassle. If you plan on switching to PDO in the future, you can continue using your try_query() function, so that it can provide with some abstraction from the underlying DB API.
